# Excel VBA clone (named) table accross a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy Template table across a sheet and leave the clones with specific names.

This is my code for creating a renamed clone:

```
Dim oTemplate As ListObject
Dim iTableCount As Long

Set oTemplate = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Item(1)
iTableCount = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Count

Dim rStart As Range
Set rStart = ActiveSheet.Range("G3")

rTemplate.Copy rStart

ActiveSheet.ListObjects(iTableCount + 1).Name = "Copied_table"
```

It counts [`ListObjects.Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/office/vba/api/excel.listobjects.count) at start, uses [`Range.copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy) to copy the Template table to `rStart`, then change name of [`ListObjects.Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/office/vba/api/excel.listobjects.item) with index 1 greater than initial [`ListObjects.Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/office/vba/api/excel.listobjects.count).

I don't like the last step. It is safe to access ListObject only by collection item index?
(I can't use name of a new table, it's auto-created and may interfere with other tables in the workbook.)

Comment: From a quick look at the docs, I can't think of any other option than to reference by index.

Comment: Can't you use something like `Listobjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rTemplate, xlYes, rStart, oTemplate.TableStyle).Name = "Copied_table"`? (not tried)

Comment: @VincentG Not working. Because `ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange...` creates a new ListObject from given Range - it leads to Run-time error 1004: Table can't overlap another table (my translation to EN).

Comment: True, the Destination parameter is not taken into account for xlSrcRange.